# Using nativeImageSource in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am learning react and came across the example [React Native ToolbarAndroid](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/toolbarandroid.html#examples) which uses "nativeImageSource" to add a logo in the toolbar.

```
 <ToolbarAndroid
            logo={nativeImageSource({
              android: 'launcher_icon',
              width: 132,
              height: 144
            })}
```

What I need help with is, what is the path of the launcher_icon? I tried putting it in the same directory and res folders, but nothing worked yet.

I also googled but could find no mention of it anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In the `android/app/src/main/res/` directory there are a few directories that start with `drawable-` and end with a few letters that correspond to different screen densities, e.g. `hdpi`. You can just place your icon, named `launcher_icon.png` in different resolutions in those directories. I think it will scale automatically if it only finds the icon in one of those folders.